# Oracle - Aggregate CLOB within PIVOT

Tags: oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions, clob, listagg

I have large user data containing their location permissions and groups of these permissions. I need to do a report containing only 1 row for every user.

There are so many permissions per one user in one group of them, I need to use my own aggregate function `LISTAGG_CLOB` which makes aggregate list but returns `CLOB` (more than 4000 characters).

This query gives me the list of all users with their permissions but it makes one row for every group of them.

```
select u.NAME,
lpg.NAME,
LISTAGG_CLOB(l.NAME)
from USERS u
left join LOCATION_PERM lp
on lp.USER_ID = u.ID
left join LOCATION l
on l.ID = lp.LOCATION
left join LOCATION_PERM_GROUP lpg
on lpg.ID = lp.GROUP
group by u.NAME, lpg.NAME
```

I tried to pivot these data but I can't get it to work, because Oracle doesn't recognize my own aggregate function as aggregate function and none aggregate funcitons (besides `LISTAGG` which is too small) is meant to aggregate strings.

Samples of what I tried are:

1)

```
select * from (
    select u.NAME as USER,
    lpg.NAME as PERM_GROUP,
    LISTAGG_CLOB(l.NAME) as PERMISSIONS
    from USERS u
    left join LOCATION_PERM lp
    on lp.USER_ID = u.ID
    left join LOCATION l
    on l.ID = lp.LOCATION
    left join LOCATION_PERM_GROUP lpg
    on lpg.ID = lp.GROUP
    group by u.NAME, lpg.NAME)
pivot (LISTAGG(PERMISSIONS) within group (order by PERMISSIONS) for PERM_GROUP in ('Global', 'Orders', 'Admin') )
```

But it produces

> Buffer too small for `CLOB` to `CHAR` or `BLOB` to `RAW` conversion
>   error

2)

```
select * from (
    select u.NAME as USER,
    lpg.NAME as PERM_GROUP,
    LISTAGG_CLOB(l.NAME) as PERMISSIONS
    from USERS u
    left join LOCATION_PERM lp
    on lp.USER_ID = u.ID
    left join LOCATION l
    on l.ID = lp.LOCATION
    left join LOCATION_PERM_GROUP lpg
    on lpg.ID = lp.GROUP
    group by u.NAME, lpg.NAME)
pivot (DISTINCT(PERMISSIONS) for PERM_GROUP in ('Global', 'Orders', 'Admin') )
```

But it says "missing expression" so I guess I can't use `DISTINCT` (or `UNIQUE`) keyword in place of aggregate function.
I also tried `MAX` and other aggregate functions but they accept only numbers as input.

Any suggestions how to pivot these data?